# python regular expression search on paths have '\'

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex in Python to parse a solution file and extract included project files. Here's what I come up with:

```
slnFileSyntax = re.compile('Project(\(\S+\)) = \"(.*?)\", \"(.*?)\"')
mo = slnFileSyntax.search('Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "all", "all\all.vcxproj", "{E305E46C-9D74-4755-BF57-29DEAEF4DCDD}"')

print mo.group(2)
print mo.group(3)
```

So I'm trying to get project name and its path. However, python seems get '\a' in all\all.vcxproj as all?ll.vcxproj. (? stands for un-recognized char)

I tried several expressions. Can anyone help?

Comment: I guess backslashing the backslash would help.

Comment: Or using `r'raw strings'`, per the docs.

Comment: yeah, forget backshlashing the backslash, @jonrsharpe you are right...that is actually exactly what there are raw strings for, I completely forgot them :)

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes. Without the "r" for a raw string, you need to escape all the backslashes. But use a raw string.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, and also thank everyone else who commented.